# System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'CricApiConsoleDemo.ConsumeAPISync' threw an exception.'

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, vs-web-site-project

[ConsumeAPISync Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beNaI.png)>System.TypeInitializationException
HResult=0x80131534
Message=The type initializer for 'CricApiConsoleDemo.ConsumeAPISync' threw an exception.
Source=CricApiConsoleDemo
StackTrace:
at CricApiConsoleDemo.ConsumeAPISync..ctor()
at CricApiConsoleDemo.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\CricAPIDemo_CSharp-master\Program.cs:line 13

Inner Exception 1:
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Visual Studio Error.[Visual Studio Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDz7B.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @Ayush Rane, ConsumeAPISync is a class you created? Based on my search, I can not find it. Please tell me how do you reference it so that I can test it.

Comment: @JackJJun-MSFT I have edited my post.I have added the screenshot of ConsumeAPISync Class.

Comment: @Charlieface Ok I will check it.